# After detach cannot findFragmentbyTag

Tags: android, android-fragments

In MainFragment at onViewCreated() I try to create nested fragment by following code ...

```
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

    MainSubAFragment mainSubAFragment = MainSubAFragment.newInstance();
    MainSubBFragment mainSubBFragment = MainSubBFragment.newInstance();

    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.contentContainer, mainSubAFragment, MainSubAFragment.class.getName())
            .add(R.id.contentContainer, mainSubBFragment, MainSubBFragment.class.getName())
            .detach(mainSubBFragment)
            .commit();

    if (fm.executePendingTransactions()) {
        showSubA();
    }
```

After executePendingTransaction I call showSubA(), but no hope return null..

```
 public void showSubA() {
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();

        MainSubAFragment mainSubAFragment = (MainSubAFragment)
                fm.findFragmentByTag(MainSubAFragment.class.getName());
        MainSubBFragment mainSubBFragment = (MainSubBFragment)
                fm.findFragmentByTag(MainSubBFragment.class.getName());

        fm.beginTransaction()
                .attach(mainSubAFragment)
                .detach(mainSubBFragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

It seem detach is a cause of problem ?? The question is .. if I call detach I cannot retreive it again @ findFragmentByTag() ??

> project sample: [dropbox download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehgdu02olg0mi3x/FragmentPlayGround.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Why are you using .getName()? Any specific reason?

Comment: @Aizen I don't want to hardcode a tag name of each Fragment. reduce typo.

Comment: oh ok, anyway, the problem is your execution. you're trying to Add but at the same time Detaching. Only the last delegate property on an Object will occur in a commit. AND YES it is a delegate core on an Object.

Comment: @Aizen you mean it skip add() property ??

Comment: No it didn't, as a delegate it will stack the call. The problem is Add = Adding. While Replace = Remove + Add.  Attach = FindTag + Add. Detach = FindTag + Remove.

Comment: so in a Sence, You add it, but you Remove it. Detach is nothing else but Remove as well with FindTag feature.

Comment: @Aizen detach vs remove, datech still keep its state in FragmentManger, however, remove  is not keep anything and gone. Is it true ? and how it become call detach() and get a remove() feature ??

Comment: I will give you an answer, hoping that you will get the Idea on that. I will try to modify just about how you approach with the Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

First Create your Fragments. It is much better to Create your Fragments in a Fragment class Instead of the Original Class name as long as you extended the Fragment class. Like this.

```
Fragment mainSubAFragment, mainSubBFragment;
```

Now we have to supply those pointers with the Fragments.

`mainSubAFragment = new MainSubAFragment();` <- No need to call the New Instance which is in the Object Class.
`mainSubBFragment = new MainSubBFragment();`

Remember they need to extended to Fragment. Which I know you did.

Now I don't know why you have to get the ChildFragmentManager but you can just directly get the FragmentManager;

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManger();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
```

Now everything is ready, we go to the Execution part.

```
        ft.add(R.id.contentContainer,mainSubAFragment,MainSubAFragment.class.getName());

    ft.add(R.id.contentContainer,mainSubBFragment,MainSubBFragment.class.getName());

       ft.commit();
```

NOTE: They will stack there Listeners, like a normal fragment does. So Unless declare in their XML not to stack there listeners, there onclick will be called if they are position on the same location.

After you Commit add this.

You would need to add another Fragment Transaction, why? Because the Commit() that you have made might not be finished, even though this is a line by line execution. Trust me, most of the time stack calls is fighting over one another.

To avoid this,

```
FragmentTransaction transaction2 = fm.beginTransaction();
fm.hide(MainSubBFragment.class.getName());
```

Summing things up.

```
     Fragment mainSubAFragment, mainSubBFragment;

      FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManger();
      FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
      FragmentTransaction transaction2;

      ft.add(R.id.contentContainer,mainSubAFragment,MainSubAFragment.class.getName());
ft.add(R.id.contentContainer,mainSubBFragment,MainSubBFragment.class.getName());

ft.commit();

     transaction2 = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction2.hide(MainSubBFragment.class.getName());
    transaction2.commit();
```

Make Sure that the Fragment Transactions and FragmentManagers is Global Variable. So they can be used by other Methods, instead of Creating a new Instance.